# How to retrieve ChartJS instance after initialization

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I'm using (have to) a framework that will eventually create a Chart with ChartJS, but it doesn't give me the instance of the chart.

Is there a way of retrieving this instance having only the canvas Id?

Comment: There's no way to. You might be able to use a modified build of ChartJS if the framework is depending on you (instead of importing ChartJS itself).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just loop through `Chart.instances`

```
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance){
  alert(instance.chart.canvas.id)
})
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bkq5Lq8b/

Comment: In v3 the "chart" property has been removed so just reference the "instance" id like this => instance.canvas.id

Answer (score 1):

If someone doesn't want to iterate over instances array, then he can get instance directly from id like this.

```
const chart = Chart.getChart("canvas-id"); //where canvas-id is the id of a canvas
```

So now chart is your instance on which you can do the other operations. Reference [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#static-getchart-key)