# How to retrieve all ECharts instance after initialization?

Tags: echarts

How do I get all ECharts instance without knowing their id's?

As I know, this approach is doable with other chart libraries like chart.js, here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36610556/3046656)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`echarts.getInstanceByDom`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.getInstanceByDom).

The question is how do you identify the echart containing DOM elements.

- The safest solution would be to search all divs and canvas elements (`target: HTMLDivElement|HTMLCanvasElement`).

```js
function getAllInstances(){
    const instances = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('canvas, div').forEach(
        function(e){
            const instance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(e);
            if(instance){
                instances.push(instance);
            }
        }
    );
    return instances;
}
```

this might be excessive for heavy pages.

- The cheekiest solution is to use the non-documented attribute `_echarts_instance_` that all echarts containers seem to have

```js
function getAllInstances(){
    const instances = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('canvas[_echarts_instance_], div[_echarts_instance_]').forEach(
        function(e){
            const instance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(e);
            if(instance){
                instances.push(instance);
            }
        }
    );
    return instances;
}
```

this is slightly unsafe, as the undocumented property can change in the future without notice.

- the solution in the code below, attempting to get the middle way, finds all `canvas` and `svg` elements and then goes up the parent element DOM chain until an instance is found or we get to the top of the document:

```js
function getAllInstances(){
    const instances = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('canvas, svg').forEach(
        function(e){
            let instance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(e);
            do{
                instance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(e);
                if(instance){
                    console.log(e)
                    break;
                }
                e = e.parentElement;
            }while(e);
            if(instance){
                instances.push(instance);
            }
        }
    );
    return instances;
}
```

Here's a test example with different types of echarts containers:

```js
const option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7],
            type: 'line'
        }
    ]
}

const myChart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container1'), null, { renderer: 'svg' });
myChart1.setOption(option);

const myChart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container2'));
myChart2.setOption(option);

const myChart3 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container3'));
myChart3.setOption(option);

function getAllInstances(){
    const instances = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('canvas, svg').forEach(
        function(e){
            let instance = null;
            do{
                instance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(e);
                if(instance){
                    break;
                }
                e = e.parentElement;
            }while(e);
            if(instance){
                instances.push(instance);
            }
        }
    );
    return instances;
}

const instances = getAllInstances();
console.log(instances.includes(myChart1), instances.includes(myChart2), instances.includes(myChart3));
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.chart {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="chart-container1"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart-container2"></div>
<canvas id="chart-container3" height="260" class="chart"></canvas>
<canvas id="non_chart_canvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
```